# JQuery .wrapall() changes elements position

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and Woocommerce.
I have product title ( the H2 ), and product image. I want to wrap them with a div.
But everything works almost perfect:
In the output I have

```js
jQuery( this ).find( 'h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title,img.wp-post-image' ).wrapAll( '<div class="prod-img-wrap col-md-3">  </div>' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod-img-wrap col-md-3">
<img class="wp-post-image" width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn.athemes.com/wp-content/uploads/Original-JPG-Image.jpg"> </img>
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Title</h2>

</div>
```

But what I need is:

```js
jQuery( this ).find( 'h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title,img.wp-post-image' ).wrapAll( '<div class="prod-img-wrap col-md-3">  </div>' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod-img-wrap col-md-3">
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Title</h2>
<img class="wp-post-image" width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn.athemes.com/wp-content/uploads/Original-JPG-Image.jpg"> </img>


</div>
```

I need the title on top, and then the image.
I tried with CSS, JS, but nothing works. 
Can you please help me?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it has been edited.

Comment: Those snippets are really confusing. Again (as I deleted my earlier comment): We need to see the structure as it is **before** you change it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you start out with

```
<img class="wp-post-image" width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn.athemes.com/wp-content/uploads/Original-JPG-Image.jpg"> </img>
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Title</h2>
```

and you want to end up with

```
<div class="prod-img-wrap col-md-3">
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Title</h2>
    <img class="wp-post-image" width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn.athemes.com/wp-content/uploads/Original-JPG-Image.jpg">
</div>
```

If so, after wrapping them, we just move the `h2` to the top of the wrapper:

```js
jQuery('h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title,img.wp-post-image').wrapAll('<div class="prod-img-wrap col-md-3">  </div>');
jQuery(".prod-img-wrap h2").each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
  });
```

```html
<img class="wp-post-image" width="100px" height="100px" src="https://cdn.athemes.com/wp-content/uploads/Original-JPG-Image.jpg"> </img>
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Title</h2>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was trying to achieve!